# Random number of Windows Updates on different computers

Tags: windows, update

After a MS Windows rollout to 90 PCs, Windows Update wants to install 30 updates on some computers and max 170 updates on others. The number differs between 30 and 170. The pattern looks random, although the computer hardware and software state is the same on each machine.

Is there a reason why some computers get only 30 updates and others 170 updates after first boot?

Comment: It's not random. The machines are in different states.

Answer (score 2):

If they were all deployed from the same image, the only possible answer is that some computers have had a chance to download the first round of updates, install them, and reboot before you've had a chance to check it. Then, after that first batch up updates, there are an additional 30 updates that are still needed.

You can verify this by looking at the date for the installed Windows Updates in Control Panel.

Comment: I found a document (http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/9/4/a94af289-a798-4143-a3f8-77004f7c2fd3/Windows%20Update%20Explained.docx) at MS website which says that each host decides randomly when it's time to install updates (to prevent server overload). "The Windows Update client on your PC checks the Windows Update server at Microsoft for the availability of new updates at random intervals, every 17 to 22 hours. The randomization ensures that the Windows Update server is not overloaded with requests for updates all at the same time." So this seems to be the explanation on the issue, thx!